# Blazor - How to call method to set user data after successful log in

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app that I'm forcing users to sign in at start up. I have put this logic in the MainLayout.razor page like so:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await SetUserInfo(user);
        }
        else
        {
            AuthMessage = "User is NOT authenticated";
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}");
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is call the SetUserInfo method after the user has logged in successfully (at the moment it will always navigate to the log in page when starting the app), but can't figure out how to do it. It seems that the OnInitializedAsync method only runs once, unless you manually refresh the page. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to use OnParametersSetAsync() in the component.

```
[CascadingParameter] protected Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            var user = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await SetUserInfo(user);                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnAfterRenderAsync

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
            if (authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
            
            }
        }
    }
```

on LoginDisplay component

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private string _authMessage;

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            wait SetUserInfo(user);
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amjad, just tried that and I'm still facing the same issue. Where would I call the "SetUserInfo" method in your example?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Would I call the LogUsername() from the MainLayout component once the user is signed in?

Comment: What does LogUsername() do

Comment: It is grabbing the signed in user claims and calls services to load user data.

Comment: To further clarify, I'm trying to load the navbar, which is set at the MainLayout. The navbar is dependent on having the user claims to load specific user options.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is this:

Add a Blazor Component, e.g. "CallMe" (shortened Code)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IDataService DataService
...

@code{
    [CascadingParameter] protected Task<AuthenticationState> AuthState { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await AuthState).User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
          var email = user.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
          var user = await DataService.GetUserAsync(email);
        }
    }
}
```

and 'call' it in LoginDisplay.razor -> Authorized Context.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <CallMe></CallMe>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogout">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```